# SQL Server query plan generation optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I've got a quite complex view that has about 100 subqueries in it's definition.

Simple statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView
```

take 2 seconds to generate the plan and execute query.Subsequent selects when the plan is cached take less than 1ms to execute.

This situation would be alright if I had only a couple of queries - performance hit only once is acceptable. The problem is that our ORM generates paging queries with parameters using CTE.
Changing parameter values(pages) causes query plan recalculation - in this case this unfortunately takes about 4 seconds!

Let's add filtering, sorting and you get the idea of what happens..

What can I do to cut down the query plan creation times or make less of them or optimize this in any other manner?

@MartinSmith "SQL Server doesn't generate a plan for each parameter value except if the text has somehow changed"

I have a query like this (I've put stars here instead of more than 120 fields list):

```
DECLARE @low int = 20;
DECLARE @high int = 300;

WITH __actualSet
AS (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ) AS __rowcnt
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5000 *
    FROM [dbo].[Project] [LPA_L1]
    ORDER BY [LPA_L1].[CreatedOn] ASC
    ) AS _tmpSet
)
SELECT *
FROM __actualSet
WHERE [__rowcnt] > @low
AND [__rowcnt] <= @high
ORDER BY [__rowcnt] ASC
```

The first time I run this query ~4s. The second time ~1ms. When I change the param values - once again 4s. Maybe I'm misinterpreting something here?

Comment: Rewrite the view to not use 100 subqueries? Though if the only thing changing is `@parameter` values this should not cause recompilation anyway.

Comment: I can't rewrite the view not to use 100 subqueries, however I'll try use projection to cut down the number of columns queried each time. This works basically the same, but still generating execution plan for each parameter value is crazy..

Comment: SQL Server doesn't generate a plan for each parameter value except if the text has somehow changed.

Comment: When the plan generation cost becomes the problem (instead of the execution cost) you have a REALLY big problem.

Comment: I've updated the quesion with more details.

Comment: Does your ORM actually generate queries like the code you posted? That uses variables not parameters. If the actual text sent to the server includes the text `DECLARE @low int = 20;DECLARE @high int = 300;` followed by the SQL directly then yes that would cause a new plan to be compiled. `ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not guaranteed to do anything deterministic BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe my ORM generates parameters, but I have tested this on variables in SSMS. I didn't know it matters. What is more I haven't noticed this `ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` fragment - LOL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test in SSMS and reuse the same plan for different values you need to parameterise the query and execute it with `sp_executesql`

```
DECLARE @low int = 20;
DECLARE @high int = 300;

EXEC sp_executesql N'
WITH __actualSet
AS (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ) AS __rowcnt
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5000 *
    FROM [dbo].[Project] [LPA_L1]
    ORDER BY [LPA_L1].[CreatedOn] ASC
    ) AS _tmpSet
)
SELECT *
FROM __actualSet
WHERE [__rowcnt] > @low
AND [__rowcnt] <= @high
ORDER BY [__rowcnt] ASC

', N'@low INT, @high INT', @low = @low, @high = @high
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This works like a charm! Less than 1ms for any parameter values!